# Serial write in linux blocking, solution for timing out?

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

I feel like this has to be a common error state for serial comms but I have yet to see a good solution.

I have set a serial port set to non blocking and I have disabled flow control.  I then use Select to determine when I can write the port.  I'm trying to write large buffers( larger than the page size, 4k, which I think is the amount of software buffering given to the port).  The first part of the write will go through but then I am blocking trying to write the rest if the serial connection is broken or the end consumer is turned off/rebooting.  I've thought about writing smaller chunks of data but I feel like eventually I will fill the buffer and run into this case again.  Is there perhaps a way to query the available buffer left before writing?  A way to change the buffer size without recompiling the kernel?

My goal is to have a way to timeout failed writes so I can flush and notify the user.  I don't want the tail end of a failed message to go through right when a device is coming back.  The serial settings(baud, stop bits etc.) may also be changing over time and I dont want them changed while I may have a write hanging out.

I've determined that I can send a thread a sigusr1 signal and that will cancel an ongoing write but this doesnt seem all that graceful.  Perhaps this is the prefered method?  Also I've looked into using aio_write but I've never used it before and I dont know its limitations.

If anyone has a good solution for timing out failed writes I'd be interested in hearing them.  Thanks.

EDIT: I've done more investigation and my question was not totally correct.  I was using psuedo serial ports and writing to them behaved differently than real serial ports.  The question would still pertain to if you had hardware flow control enabled or you had to use psuedo serial ports.

Comment: By setting the serial port to non blocking, do you mean you've set the file descriptor to non-blocking with a call to fcntl() or the O_NONBLOCK flag to open()?

Comment: I set it on the call to open.  Do you feel setting it with fcntl would lead to different results?

Comment: If the file descriptor is properly set to blocking and everything else was done right, this sounds like a kernel bug. A nonblocking `write` should not block for any reason, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the thread a signal is the best way to do it, though what I would do is use a `timer` to set the timeout; if I remember correctly this is what I've done in the past(pesudo-code):

```
timer_create();
int value = write( fd, buffer, buff_len );
if( value < 0 && errno == EINTR ) {
    /* We were interrupted by a signal - write failed. */
}else if( value < 0 ){
    timer_delete();
    /* other error */
}else if( value != buff_len){
    timer_delete();
    /* did not write out entire buffer */
}else{
    timer_delete();
    /* Write should be good */
}
```

see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/timer_create.html

Comment: See my edit above.  This is a good solution for writing with hardware flow control.  You can also temporarily disable flow control in another thread to allow the bytes to drain.